# How to serve .jasper file with HTTP Server?

Tags: java, http, jasper-reports, apache-tomee

I am creating HTTP server with [Tomee](http://tomee.apache.org/), i am placed jasper report file (`.jasper`) in `webapp` directory. if i access `http://localhost:8080/test.jasper` in browser, the browser will prompt to download the file.

In my java project i'm creating simple code to access that link and then preview the report. I use [async-http-client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) library for request.

```
DefaultAsyncHttpClient client = new DefaultAsyncHttpClient();
BoundRequestBuilder brb = client.prepareGet("http://localhost:8765/qa/test.jasper");
Future<InputStream> f = brb.execute(new AsyncCompletionHandler<InputStream>() {
    @Override
    public InputStream onCompleted(Response resp) {
        try {
            String[][] data = {{"Jakarta"},{"Surabaya"},{"Solo"},{"Denpasar"}};
            String[] columnNames = {"City"};
            DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

            Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();

            JasperPrint jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                resp.getResponseBodyAsStream(),
                params,
                new JRTableModelDataSource(dtm)
            );
            JasperViewer jpView = new JasperViewer(jPrint,false);
            jpView.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            jpView.setSize(800, 600);
            jpView.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            jpView.setVisible(true);

        } catch (JRException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return resp.getResponseBodyAsStream();
    }
});
```

From my code above, i got an error `Error loading object from InputStream`

normally i can use

```
InputStream input = MainContext.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

But i want to replace file input stream with http request (stream too).

How exactly i can serve `.jasper` file with http server...?

Comment: Typically, `.jasper` files aren't served. Rather, `.pdf`, `.csv`, or other output files are made available after the server-side executes the `.jasper` file. Unless you're expecting the user to download the `.jasper` file, load it into Jaspersoft Studio (which implies downloading and installing it), and run it themselves (plus manage database connections)?

Comment: Yes i want users to download `.jasper` file, via java application i create, after users download the report, the report will shows in users as regular report.

Answer (score 0):

`Error loading object from InputStream` error came from corrupt `InputStream`, if i download `.jasper` file normally via browser and execute the report with `JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path to file)` it doesn't works too, because tomee give corrupt file (the source file not corrupt).

My own solution is read source file as stream, convert it to base64 encode, and serve it via HTTP API protocol.

```
finput = new FileInputStream(sPath);
byte[] bFile = Base64.getEncoder().encode(IOUtils.toByteArray(finput));

String sFile = new String(bFile);
```

inside client side, i received it as body string, decode the base64 string, convert it to `InputStream` and Finally execute the report with `InputStream`.

```
byte[] bBody = Base64.getDecoder().decode(sBody);
InputStream mainReport = new ByteArrayInputStream(bBody);
return JasperFillManager.fillReport(mainReport, params);
```